# Редирект в htaccess offers/id60=300 -> offers/300

Tags: .htaccess, apache, apache2

Все привет, нужен директ вида: offers/id60=300 -> offers/300

Почему-то такой вариант не работает?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/offers/?id(.*)=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/offers/?id(.*)=(.*)$ /offers/$2  [R=301,L]
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: В оригинале запроса нет знака «?». В RewriteRule он присутствует. Описка, я так понимаю.

Comment: Да, спасибо, знак вопроса нужен.

Comment: Тогда вместо `%{REQUEST_URI}` надо `%{QUERY_STRING}` - это как раз разберет строку после знака "?". Т.е. как-то так: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^id(\d+)=(\d+)$`